# How to configure eslint indent for WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, eslint

How to set `"indent"` in `.eslintr.json` to match the default used in WebStorm?

[image]

Everything I've tried so far, as per [the official documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) can't match it:

- `"indent": ["error", 2]` - gives many `Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4`
- `"indent": ["error", 4]` - gives many `Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8`
- `"indent": ["error", 8]` - gives many `Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 4`

My complete eslint configuration:

```
{
  "env": {
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jasmine": true
  },
  "extends": "eslint:recommended",
  "parserOptions": {
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-else-return": "error",
    "no-multi-spaces": "error",
    "no-whitespace-before-property": "error",
    "camelcase": "error",
    "new-cap": "error",
    "no-console": "error",
    "comma-dangle": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "indent": ["error", 4],
    "quotes": [
      "error",
      "single"
    ],
    "semi": [
      "error",
      "always"
    ]
  }
}
```

As I type the code, I always use `Ctrl+Alt+L` to auto-format the code, and the code formatting produced doesn't comply with any eslint settings.

---

**UPDATE**

As was asked, a code example for `"indent": ["error", 4]`:

**For this code:** (formatted via Ctrl+Alt+L)

```
const a = 123;
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        return 1;
    case 2:
        return 2;
    case 3:
        return 3;
    default:
        break;
}
```

**results in:**

```
3:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4
4:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
5:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4
6:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
7:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4
8:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
9:1  error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4
10:1  error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
```

**example 2**

```
obj.format('text', {
        value: '${two}'
    }
);
```

**results in:**

```
2:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
3:1   error  Expected indentation of 0 spaces but found 4
```

**example 3**

```
return begin()
    .then(() => {
            return callback()
                .then(data => {
                    success = true;
                    return commit();
                }, reason => {
                    return rollback();
                })
        },
        function (reason) {
            update(false, false, reason);
            return $p.reject(reason);
        });
```

results in:

```
3:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 12
4:1   error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 16
5:1   error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 20
6:1   error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 20
7:1   error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 16
8:1   error  Expected indentation of 16 spaces but found 20
9:1   error  Expected indentation of 12 spaces but found 16
10:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
11:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
12:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 12
13:1   error  Expected indentation of 8 spaces but found 12
14:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 8
```

Comment: So you are getting eslint errors? When exactly?

Comment: @ush189 all over the place, that's the thing, no matter what I've tried, WebStorm seems to have a mind of its own about code formatting.

Comment: Your settings look fine. Could you post your eslint config?

Comment: @ush189 I have update my question for that ;)

Comment: I have the same webstorm settings and I just copied your eslint config and everything seem to work fine. So I think you also need to show us a screenshot of your code with the error message ;)

Comment: @ush189 is your automatically formatted via Ctrl + Alt + L? Mine all is, and that produces formatting that doesn't comply with the eslint. I've added this in the question also.

Comment: Yes, auto format should also work. You have to show us the code.

Comment: @ush189 code example added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Switch-Case seems to be a special case for eslint regarding indentation. Per default the `case` clauses are not indented relative to the `switch`:

> "SwitchCase" (default: 0) enforces indentation level for case clauses
>   in switch statements

See here for an example: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent#switchcase

You need to set `SwitchCase` option to 1 like so:

```
"indent": [
    "error", 
    4, 
    {"SwitchCase": 1}
]
```

So your complete eslint config will now look like this:

```
{
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jasmine": true
    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": {
    },
    "rules": {
        "no-else-return": "error",
        "no-multi-spaces": "error",
        "no-whitespace-before-property": "error",
        "camelcase": "error",
        "new-cap": "error",
        "no-console": "error",
        "comma-dangle": "error",
        "no-var": "error",
        "indent": ["error", 4, {"SwitchCase": 1}],
        "quotes": [
            "error",
            "single"
        ],
        "semi": [
            "error",
            "always"
        ]
    }
}
```

Regarding your 2nd example I think it is common to write it like this:

```
obj.format('text', {
    value: '${two}'
});
```

Both parenthesis are opened on the same line, so you close them on the same line. If you use auto format on that lines, they will not change.

The third example looks a bit tricky. I don't know if you can get eslint and auto format on the same page for that one. I personally would prefer the eslint way, but I don't know if you can tweak the auto format to do it like that.

Edit: You could write it like that:

```
return begin()
    .then(() => callback()
        .then(data => {
            success = true;
            return commit();
        }, reason => {
            return rollback();
        }),
        function(reason) {
            update(false, false, reason);
            return $p.reject(reason);
        });
```

Comment: I have added another in the question. Is that another special case? I wonder how many of them will be, should I go through all the code...

Comment: Added example 3 with another indent issue. Could you, please, update your answer for those extra cases.

Comment: About your comments on example 2, I don't understand how this is supposed to help. You are saying there my example is valid, and that auto-format won't change it. The auto-format doesn't change it, the eslint produces the errors as shown in the question.

Comment: I mean that when you write it like I did, then auto format will not change it and eslint will not show any errors.

Comment: In example 2 - got it, thanks! It's just example 3 now that's left.

Comment: For example 3 I tried to set the auto format settings to the way eslint wants, but it didn't work, sorry.

Comment: Is there at least a different way to write it for a work-around? I can't seem to find a way to make it work.

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't seem to work, still getting plenty of errors.

Comment: Clarification. I can only get it to work after manual re-formatting. But just as I do Ctrl+Alt+L on the file, the formatting for example 3 gets broken again. Are you saying that it is impossible to make eslint work with WebStorm in those cases? If so, I will need to raise an issue against WebStorm / ESLint.

Comment: If you update your answer about example 3, explaining that it is in fact not possible, i.e. not without manually re-formatting the code, then I will accept the answer, and pursue the issue against the WebStorm.

Comment: Let's try this: Please tick the checkbox "Indent all chained calls in a group" in your WebStorm settings, then use my code of example 3. I think it will stay with auto format and eslint is fine with it.

Comment: Tried that, it worked only for the simplified example I gave, as it had just one level, but not for the nested once that I skipped :(

Comment: I accept the answer, because it is probably as good as I could get. But I never got the example 3 to work right, not for promise chains with nesting.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed it by added the indent configuration into the file **.eslintrc.js**

```
module.exports = {
    "rules": {
        "indent": ["error", 4]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are getting the error due to `WebStorm` formatting.

---

### Solution

In `webstorm`:

- `File` -> `Setting`
- Go to `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `HTML`
- In `Do not indent children of`, add tag `script`.
- Then format the source code again.

Then the error should be gone.

---

Screen shot:

[image]